# Is there any way where i can upload my images and use networkImage flutter

Tags: flutter, networkimageview

I want to get my own app images from the NetworkImage but I am not able to figure out where I can upload.

Comment: please be more clarified and explain more. thank you. see this topic to know how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I think you want an Image Host. You can try imbgg.com or imgur.com
In ImgBB, Sign in, upload the images you want and under Embed codes, select Direct Links.
Use these links as URLs in your `NetworkImage()`